# How to disable DatePicker in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

As You know com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.**DatePicker** haven't method setEnabled(boolean). I have DatePicker with ValueChangeHandler and all what I need is disable datepicker (code in onValueChange shouldn't work).

Of course I can do:

> boolean disable;
>
> datePicker.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler() {
>
> ```
>         @Override
>         public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
>             if(!disable) {
>                  // my code here
>             }
>         }
>     });
> ```

but I won't do this. I want write something like that:

> datePicker.setEnabled(false);

Any ideas?

GWT 2.3.0

Comment: Just a comment about your GWT version: you really should get the 2.5.0 one, mainly because of the compiler optimizations.

Comment: Are you trying to disable clicks on the DatePicker and the resulting UI change that including month selector etc...

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used GWT in a while, so this is more of a pointer than an answer, but I wanted to include several links so used the answer box ;).

DatePicker is a [Composite](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html), so I don't think you can't enable/disable it directly. But you can add a preview handler to disable events, or throw a panel over it (and grey it out, for instance). See this answer for info on that: [Disable user interaction in a GWT container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061699/disable-user-interaction-in-a-gwt-container)

As a general note, everything that extends from [FocusWidget](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusWidget.html) is enable/disable-able, but composites are collections of other widgets so they work differently.