# Disable/mask TabItem's content panel in ExtGwt

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have a TabPanel with two TabItems in ExtGwt. I want to make both the TabItem selectable/clickable but want to disable/read-only the content panel in the TabItem so that user can not perform any action like input text in the textbox or select any field etc. I tried various approaches but it didnot worked for me. I don't want to make the whole tab disable.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2063082/1313968

An alternative approach is to disable all components in the panel, for example just pass your `ContentPanel` to the following method:

```java
private void containerSetEnabled(final Container container, final boolean enabled) {
  for (int widgetIndex = 0; widgetIndex < container.getWidgetCount(); ++widgetIndex) {
    final Widget widget = container.getWidget(widgetIndex);
    if (widget instanceof Container) {
      containerSetEnabled((Container)widget, enabled);
    }
    else if (widget instanceof Component) {
      ((Component)widget).setEnabled(false);
    }
  }
}
```